# How to boot into Windows 7 after install Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, windows-7

My computer had Windows 7. Then I installed Ubuntu.

But after the installation I can only go to Ubuntu.

Comment: Try the search box at the top right.  With the way this is worded it sounds like it's not a real question.

Comment: Could you be more specific? By providing more details about the problem you are facing you help the community to help you.

Comment: Does the computer give you a choice of OS to boot? How did you install Ubuntu? Did you install it alongside windows?

Comment: possible duplicated: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/62483)

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq): When you post a new question, other users will almost immediately see it and try to provide good answers. This often happens in a matter of minutes, **so be sure to check back frequently** when your question is still new for the best response.

Comment: @Lucio: I think the OP is having the opposite problem - booting Windows after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: @NathanOsman I know, but many users (me inclusive) has **repaired the GRUB** with some of the answers there. I know that the title can confuse a bit, but some times, it doesn't differ if you installed Ubuntu or Windows the last time.